# IQueryable does not contain definition for 'Where' Linq, C#

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I have a query that I altered a bit, made it into a generic Iqueryable.
However now all the code that relied on it to be more specific are throwing an error saying 'IQueryable does not contain definition for 'Where'

How do I fix this so my Iqueryable can have a 'where' statement

```
IQueryable query = _db
                .BatchPayments
                .Where(
                    bp => ValidBatchStatuesIds.Contains(bp.Batch.BatchStatusId)
                        && (!OnlineBatchTypes.Contains(bp.Batch.BatchTypeId)
                            || (OnlineBatchTypes.Contains(bp.Batch.BatchTypeId)))
                )
                .GroupBy(i => i.BatchId)
                .Select(i => new
                {
                    Amount = i.Sum(j => j.Amount)
                });

if (model.AmountFrom.HasValue && model.AmountFrom.Value > 0)
            {
                query = query.Where(bp => bp.Amount >= model.AmountFrom); // This is the line it bugs out on that I need to work
                hasInput = true;
            }
```

Comment: It needs to be IQuerable <T>

Comment: Points to Scott... but since it returns an anonymous type you have to use `var`.

Comment: @DStanley If that were the case (it's not) then the `Where` earlier in the snippet wouldn't compile, nor would the `GroupBy` or `Select` compile.

Answer (score 7):

[`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.where.aspx) is an extension method on `IQueryable<T>`, not `IQueryable`.  You'll need to make `query` of type `IQueryable<T>` to further filter the query.  You can do this by either using `var` or projecting out the actual amount, rather than an anonymous object with an amount, allowing `query` to be `IQueryable<decimal>` (or whatever the numeric type of `Amount` is).